# Many foreign keys to one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure even how to google it so I decided to ask here. I have two tables in my MySQL database:

Table: `users`

```
 user_id | user_name | user_surname 
---------+-----------+-------------
 111     | Tom       | Hanks
 112     | Martin    | Dubravka     
 113     | Gary      | Muller
 114     | Grzegorz  | Kowalewski
 115     | Chris     | Anderson
 116     | John      | Smith
```

and

Table: `best_users`

```
 id    | best_user_1 | best_user_2 | best_user_3 | best_user_4 | best_user_5 | best_user_6          
-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------
 1     |  115        |  114        |  112        |  116        |  111        |  113
```

`best_user_id`  field is the Foreign Key to field `user_id` in `users` table.

What I would like to achieve is to get (best in one query):

```
 id    | best_user_1  | user_name1 | user_surname1 | best_user_2 | user_name2 | user_surname2 | best_user_3 | ...
-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-------------+------------+---------------+-------------+----
 1     |  115         | Chris      | Anderson      | 114         |  Grzegorz  | Kowalewski    | 112         | ...
```

Is it possible in one query in pure SQL? Of course I could get `best_users` first and then get `user_name` based on `best_user_x` field. Should be it done in some kind of JOIN?

Regards

M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you like typing... you need to `JOIN` to the `users` table 6 times, once for each `best_user`:

```
SELECT id,
       best_user_1,
       u1.user_name AS user_name1,
       u1.user_surname AS user_surname1,
       ...
       best_user_6,
       u6.user_name AS user_name6,
       u6.user_surname AS user_surname6
FROM best_users
JOIN users u1 ON u1.user_id = best_users.best_user_1
...
JOIN users u6 ON u6.user_id = best_users.best_user_6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d5e21a0202473625f045649e91a7e01c)

Comment: I tried that with JOIN but did not get results as you provided. Will check at home but seems to be exactly what I need!

Comment: @user2807536 based on the data you have given this does work (see the demo). No need to accept until you've tested though...